# Jetpack Compose Button with gradient background?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to create Button with gradient background?

```
@Composable
fun GradientButtonExample() {

    val horizontalGradientBrush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            Color(0xffF57F17),
            Color(0xffFFEE58),
            Color(0xffFFF9C4)
        )
    )


    val verticalGradientBrush = Brush.verticalGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            Color(0xff4E342E),
            Color(0xff8D6E63),
            Color(0xffD7CCC8)
        )
    )

    Button(onClick = {}) {
        Text(
            text = "Horizontal Gradient",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(brush = horizontalGradientBrush)
        )
    }

    Button(onClick = {}) {
        Text(
            text = "Vertical Gradient",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(brush = verticalGradientBrush)
        )
    }
}
```

Adding gradient to `Text` with `background(brush)` leaves a margin between `Button` and `Text`. When i set background of button with `modifier.background(brush = horizontalGradientBrush)`, `Button` is drawn with primary color, basically nothing happens. Is it possible to set background of `Button`, not other components, with gradient colors?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Compose **1.0.0-alpha10**

You could do someething like this:

```
@Composable
fun GradientButton(
    text: String,
    gradient : Brush,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit = { },
) {
    Button(
        modifier = modifier,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Transparent),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(),
        onClick = { onClick() },
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(gradient)
                .then(modifier),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {
            Text(text = text)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
@Composable
private fun Content() {

val gradient =
    Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(Color(0xFF28D8A3), Color(0xFF00BEB2)))

    Column {
        GradientButton(
            text = "Gradient Button - Max Width",
            gradient = gradient,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
        )
        GradientButton(
            text = "Gradient Button - Wrap Width",
            gradient = gradient,
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Result sample:

[image]

Comment: update: change background color to containercolor 






{ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Transparent)}

to 

ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent)

Comment: This solution is not working anymore. Please update it. Compose Version: 1.2.0

Comment: This becomes odd when using a padding on the external modifier.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you don't need the button... You can achieve this result using a simple `Text`...

```
Text(
    text = "Click Me",
    style = TextStyle(color = Color.White),
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = {})
        .background(
            Brush.verticalGradient(
                colors = listOf(
                    Color.Blue,
                    Color.Green
                )
            ),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
        )
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
)
```

Comment: then It is not a button! it's just a clickable text. Most important difference between button and clickable text is using of `interactionSource`

Answer (score 5):

Jetpack Compose is so flexible about creating Button or any other components, basically `Button` is `Row` inside a `Surface` with content padding as

```
private val ButtonHorizontalPadding = 16.dp
private val ButtonVerticalPadding = 8.dp
```

So it's possible to set padding to 0 and set padding after setting gradient background for `Text` such as in the snippet below.

```
Button(contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp), onClick = {}) {
    Text(
        text = "Vertical Gradient",
        modifier = Modifier
            .preferredHeight(ButtonDefaults.MinHeight)
            .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            .background(brush = verticalGradientBrush)
            .padding(8.dp)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Implementation based on the default Button composable with all its parameters and customisation options.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun GradientButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    gradient: Brush,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
    disabledContentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
    disabledBackgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.12f)
        .compositeOver(MaterialTheme.colors.surface),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val actualElevation = elevation?.elevation(enabled, interactionSource)?.value ?: 0.dp
    val actualContentColor = if (enabled) contentColor else disabledContentColor
    val background = if (enabled) {
        Modifier.background(brush = gradient)
    } else {
        Modifier.background(color = disabledBackgroundColor)
    }
    
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .shadow(actualElevation, shape, true)
            .then(background),
        shape = shape,
        color = Color.Transparent,
        contentColor = actualContentColor.copy(alpha = 1f),
        border = border,
        elevation = 0.dp,
        onClick = onClick,
        enabled = enabled,
        role = Role.Button,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        indication = rememberRipple()
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides actualContentColor.alpha) {
            ProvideTextStyle(
                value = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(
                            minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                            minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
                        )
                        .padding(contentPadding),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    content = content
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Example screenshot with and without Modifier.fillMaxWidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odykL.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The most flexible way would be to use a `TextButton` with `Modifier.drawBehind()`.

`TextButton` doesn't draw any background of its own, but behaves like a button.

`Modifier.drawBehind()` gives you full control over what you want to draw: gradients, geometrical shapes, etc.

```kotlin
TextButton(modifier = Modifier.drawBehind { }) {
  Text("Help")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Button from Material3 this is working for me:

```
Button(
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .background(
        brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
            colors = listOf(
                Color.Blue,
                Color.Green,
            )
        ), shape = ButtonDefaults.shape
    )
    .height(ButtonDefaults.MinHeight),
onClick = {},
colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent)
) {
    Text("Button content")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

GradientButton file be like:

```
@Composable
fun GradientButton(
    text: String,
    textColor: Color,
    gradient: Brush,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(),
        onClick = { onClick() })
    {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(gradient)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = text, color = textColor)
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt file

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            // Row is used for align the buttons in center of screen
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                // this is the first button
                GradientButton(
                    text = "Button1", textColor = Color.Black, gradient = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(
                            c1,
                            c2,
                            c1
                        )
                    )
                ) {}

                // Spacer is used to give the space between two buttons
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))

                // This is second button
                GradientButton(
                    text = "Button2", textColor = Color.Black, gradient = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(
                            c3,
                            c4,
                            c3
                        )
                    )
                ) {}

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Color.kt file

```
[val c1 = Color(0xFFE9F190)
val c2 = Color(0xFFF5DB0B)

val c3 = Color(0xFFF79F1E)
val c4 = Color(0xFFFF5722)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

This is a edited version of @Aburg 's code as per compose-bom:2023.06.01 version

```
@Composable
fun GradientButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    gradient: Brush,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    elevation: Dp,
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
    disabledContentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0f),
    disabledBackgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.12f)
        .compositeOver(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val actualContentColor = if (enabled) contentColor else disabledContentColor
    val background = if (enabled) {
        Modifier.background(brush = gradient)
    } else {
        Modifier.background(color = disabledBackgroundColor)
    }

    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .shadow(elevation, shape, true)
            .then(background),
        shape = shape,
        color = Color.Transparent,
        contentColor = actualContentColor.copy(alpha = 1f),
        border = border,
        shadowElevation = 0.dp,
        onClick = onClick,
        enabled = enabled,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides actualContentColor) {
            ProvideTextStyle(
                value = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(
                            minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                            minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
                        )
                        .padding(contentPadding),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    content = content
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a box as a background for clickable element. And then add modifier .background to it, with  brush+horizontal gradient, as a parameter.

```
                  Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(
                            brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                                listOf(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue),
                                10.0f,
                                20.0f
                            ), shape = CircleShape
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

For `compose-bom` `2023.06.00`, you can just set button color to `transparent` and then set `background` from `modifier`.

```
Button(
    onClick = { onClick() },
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(RoundCorner.Small),
    modifier = modifier.background(DarkOcean_Gradient1, RoundedCornerShape(RoundCorner.Small)),
    contentPadding = contentPadding,
) {
    Text(text = text, style = h500, color = Neutral0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've honestly haven't found a solution that convinces me %100. On one hand I want a button that whether if I use a gradient or solid background, their sizes and touchable areas are the same. I've tried using the background modifier but have had some trouble when using different shapes or varied button sizes. I've come up with two different solutions:

**First**, checking out the `Jetsnack` project from the official Compose samples, I found a gradient button: `JetsnackButton`. It's built on top of a Surface, `JetsnackSurface` which is modified to look and act as a `Button`.

Link to project:
https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetsnack

The **second**, was to use a `Modifier` like so in my `Box`. This was what I found worked best I then wanted to modify the `Button`s height, or added an outline. Some of the `Modifiers` in other comments, if you combine a gradient and an outline, the shapes don't fit with each other.

```
Button(
    ... // the usual button params but set content padding to 0
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .defaultMinSize(
                minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
            )
            .fillMaxHeight()
            // gradient brush and button shape
            .background(brush, shape)
            // apply the content padding here not the button itself
            .padding(contentPadding),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        // use a row since button uses a row scope
        Row {
            // since you are in a row scope you could also pass in
            // your content as a parameter and call it from here
            Text(text = text)
        }
    }
}
```

You would of course have your `MyGradientButton` or whatever wrap this `Button` and take in any necessary parameters.