# How to set gradient background in TopAppBar using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set the gradient background of my `TopAppBar`:

My code:

```
TopAppBar(
    modifier = Modifier.background(
        Brush.horizontalGradient(
            colors = listOf(
                Color.Red,
                Color.Green
            )
        )
    ),
    title = { Text("UI Components") },
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
)
```

Result:

[image: rendered TopAppBar]

I found this post: [Jetpack Compose Button with gradient background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65542068/jetpack-compose-button-with-gradient-background) for button - so I set backgroundColor transparent and custom background via a modifier. Sadly in my case, there is an additional shadow around text which I don't know how to remove. What should I change or maybe TopAppBar is just not designed to be used using gradient and I should write something completely custom?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This shadow is caused by default `elevation`. Set it to zero:

```
TopAppBar(
    modifier = Modifier.background(
        Brush.horizontalGradient(
            colors = listOf(
                Color.Red,
                Color.Green
            )
        )
    ),
    title = { Text("UI Components") },
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    elevation = 0.dp
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In TopAppBar from Material3 like this:

```
TopAppBar(
    modifier = Modifier.background(
    Brush.horizontalGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            Color.Red,
            Color.Green
            )
        )
    ),
    title = { Text("UI Components") },
    colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent, navigationIconContentColor = onPrimaryColor, titleContentColor = onPrimaryColor),
)
```

notice of  containerColor = Color.Transparent

Answer (score 1):

In latest TopAppbar
you cannot set
  `backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,` instead you have to use

```
colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
            containerColor = Color.Transparent
        )
```